# What do think about a linctionary?

Tags: feature-request, languages

I have been wondering if should devote my time to building a dictionary with new terminology updated already, so that the red, curly line doesn't show up questioning if you meant to spell Linux, or Ubuntu, EasyBCD, or 4g that way.

The current way the dictionaries have it is when the red squiggle shows we are given the option to update the dictionary, use the dictionary database for correct spelling, or leave it. Leaving it, leaves the correction process to happen again.

If I seem dry in writing this, don't be surprised, the question is no more boring that the correction process. After 50 or so corrections I get a little perturbed with the process.

Would you support such an undertaking?

The reason I ask this question is: Often my work in under appreciated. Whether or not I work my elbows off, "this is just is", is the response I get and even though this work needs undertaken(1); If I write the new dictionary, It is to help others. Most people are affected by the dictionary as Word programs and BBrowsers all use this dictionaries system. The only word in this comment with the squiggled line on this explanation for me is that "browsers" with the two Bs and this one, one for the error "BBrowsers" and "Bs" which isn't an error, It is ambiguous. And this is a major undertaking; For, "rofl", "LMAO", I have seen the "correcting" fluid on many posts telling me my cool internet markup, isn't cool, rofl.

(1) It is a job for long winters, and one is coming. It would save in editing, and it IS a dictionary, after all, it's not just MOO, and so on...

My podiatrist has a dictionary that listens for words in his field. Says the dictionary carries podiatry terms and this makes reports cheaper and this saves him money, quite a lot of it in fact.

Comment: Would be an interesting endeavor.